# How do i change a list of values in a dictionary to a set of values?

Tags: python

So inside the dictionary, I have values that are lists with [] brackets. But I want to change them into {} brackets. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

From:

```
{hello: ['1', '2', '3']}
```

To:

```
{hello: {'1', '2', '3'}}
```

Comment: `dict` should contain pairs `{ key: value }`.

Comment: There's no dictionary of values first of all; it is a set.

Comment: `hello` is not a valid key for your dictionary - it is an undefined variable. please [edit] and add a working [mcve] including what you tried to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the list inside the dictionary into a set like you would with any other list, too:

```
>>> a = {'hello': ['1', '2', '3']}
>>> a
{'hello': ['1', '2', '3']}
>>> a['hello'] = set(a['hello'])
>>> a
{'hello': {'2', '3', '1'}}
```

Sets aren't ordered, which explains the mixed-up order of `{'2', '3', '1'}`.

Also, you didn't define your dictionary key `hello` in your question so I used a simple string here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "hello" is a variable:

```
 d = {hello: ['1', '2', '3']}
 dn = { k: set(v) for k, v in d.items() } #iterate through the dict and replace the lists by sets
```